# create a dynamic two dimensional array in python (loop)

Tags: python

i am trying to create a two-dimensional array in python..In my php i have this code:

```
$i = 1;
$arr= array();
        foreach($mes as $res){

            $arr[$i]->type = $res->item;
            $arr[$i]->action = $res->title;
$i++
}
```

how can i make that code in python? i need to built that code dynamically for the foreach loop as you can see in the code above..i need to assign the values..arr[1]['type'] = 'blabla', arr[1]['action] = 'blabla'..i hope you understand what i am trying to do

i have done this but doesnt work:

```
i = 1

for res in mes:

    fa = [i]

    fa[i].append(['type'])

    fa[i]['type'].append(res['item'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *list comprehension* with nested dictionaries is a simple way to do this:

```
arr = [{'type': res['item'], 'action': res['title']} for res in mes]
```

---

The first item (and others similarly by changing the index) in `arr` can then be accessed with:

```
arr[0]['type'] # or arr[0]['action'] 
#   ^ indices of lists in Python start from zero
```

Comment: vars_arr = [{'type': res['item'], 'action': resp['title']} for res in mes]
print(vars_arr[1]['type'])   it gives me error..list index out of range..

Comment: ok..i ve got it now..its zero based..thanks man..what if i want to create a 3 dimensional array? is the same procedure? Also how can i make an if statement in two-dimensional array.. example.. if arr[i]['type'] == 'something' ??

Comment: @JaenYonten The concept is the same. In the 3D case you'll be having nested comprehensions